# Get JSON response In Codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am passing the Object from fiddler to the service written in codeigniter. My Object is something look like this :

**My Response :**

```
   {
   "GetResponse":{
      "OrgName":"adfasd",
      "OrgAdr1":"asdf",
      "OrgAdr2":"NA",
      "ProductList":[
          {
               "ProductID":8724,
               "Pallets":0,
               "Pieces":0,
               "Description":"sdfsd"
          }
       ]
   }
}
```

**What I want :**

I want to save the response as a JSON Object in codeigniter and also want to fetch the JSON Object or Array inside the main Object.

**What I tried :**

My service method in codeigniter is something like this :

```
public function Save()
{
     $Data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
     echo $Data;
}
```

But I am getting nothing in **Response Body** inside Fiddler.

If I use this code :

```
$Data = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $Data;
```

then it is showing me the response but in the form of String. I want to save it as an JSON Object.

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here ?

Comment: your response in not a valid json string.check this here http://json.parser.online.fr

Comment: @RajeevRanjan It was Just an Extra ","(Comma). I resolve It Plz check It Now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this code:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

$Data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
```

now, you will get `$Data` as a array.

and you get value by `$Data['name']`.

Answer (score 2):

`json_decode()` parses a json string to a php variable in the form of an object or associative array. `json_encode()` does the reverse.

I think what is happening is that `php://input` is already in json format. When you run it through `json_decode()` you turn it into a php object which when `echo`ed should throw an error like

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string ....

If error reporting is suppressed the script stopped there and you get nothing echoed.

Answer (score 0):

To encode any value into JSON we must use `json_encode()`. what mistake you have done that you are decoding a non json object. So the result in null.

```
 public function Save()
    {
         $Data = json_encode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
         echo $Data;
    }
```

Comment: This does not make any sense. You should also explain your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

[json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) return either an object or an array ,so your save() should be like this

```
public function Save()
{
     $Data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r( $Data);
}
```

output will be :-

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetResponse] => stdClass Object
        (
            [OrgName] => adfasd
            [OrgAdr1] => asdf
            [OrgAdr2] => NA
            [ProductList] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [ProductID] => 8724
                            [Pallets] => 0
                            [Pieces] => 0
                            [Description] => sdfsd
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public function Save()
{
     $Data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
     var_dump($Data);
}
```