# How to send values from Backbone to a CodeIgniter controller

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, backbone.js

I am making a small application form using Backbone.js and CodeIgniter but I am having problem with connection to controller.

Can anyone please provide me the full code for that?

My controller name is `verfylogin`. I have taken username and password from the user, and I have to pass it to the controller.

```
$(function(){

        var Credentials = Backbone.Model.extend({});

        var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
          el: $("#login-form"),

          events: {
            "click #login": "login"
          },

          initialize: function(){
            var self = this;

            this.username = $("#username");
            this.password = $("#password");

            this.username.change(function(e){
              self.model.set({username: $(e.currentTarget).val()});
            });

            this.password.change(function(e){
              self.model.set({password: $(e.currentTarget).val()});
            });
          },

          login: function(){
            var username= this.model.get('username');
            var password = this.model.get('password');
            console.log(username,password);
          }
        });

        window.LoginView = new LoginView({model: new Credentials()});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please [read the Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#), look at the examples and test them to really understand how it works. Also, take a look at the [Backbone.js tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/backbone.js/info).

It's irrelevant what is used for the API (backend), Backbone communicates with the backbend through a REST API which consist of URLs.

To link a Backbone model with a endpoint URL, override the [`urlRoot` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot).

```
var Credentials = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // Specify the endpoint URL here
    urlRoot: "api/endpoint" // relative
    // urlRoot: "http://example.com/api/endpoint" // or absolute
});
```

Then, use the Backbone [view's `events` hash](http://backbonejs.org/#View-events) to manage events within the view. Avoid manually binding jQuery events.

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click #login": "login",
        "change #username": "onUsernameChange",
        "change #password": "onPasswordChange"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        // create the model here
        this.model = new Credentials();

        // cache jQuery object within the view
        this.$username = this.$("#username");
        this.$password = this.$("#password");
    },

    login: function() {
        // just call save to make a post request with the data.
        this.model.save();
    },

    onUsernameChange: function(e) {
        this.model.set({ username: this.$username.val() });
    },
    onPasswordChange: function(e) {
        this.model.set({ password: this.$password.val() });
    }
});

var loginView = new LoginView({ el: "#login-form" });
```

That way, the context (`this`) is available in the events callbacks. Avoid hard-coding the `el` property and prefer passing it on the initialization of a new view instance.

## Handling JSON data posted to a CodeIgniter controller

Since I don't use CodeIgniter, I will refer you to other resources.

- [Working with restful services in CodeIgniter](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814)
- [Retrieve JSON POST data in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602890/retrieve-json-post-data-in-codeigniter/38656283#38656283)
- [Post JSON to Codeigniter controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596216/post-json-to-codeigniter-controller)
- [Get JSON response In Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027205/get-json-response-in-codeigniter)
- [Code Igniter - How to return Json response from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821492/code-igniter-how-to-return-json-response-from-controller)

Comment: i understood that one but how can i pass it to controller of my codeigniter with this.(model.save) will it goes directly to the controller.where i need to sepcify my url.

Comment: @gopiputta I added details on where to put the URL in the backbone model. I also added additional info on CodeIgniter, unfortunately, I don't use it so I can't provide specific help on it.